# Does cURL increase bounce rate on Google Analytics report?

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics

While developing website up time monitoring application, I do send a cURL request to see whatever the site is running or down, If down then it also try to detect the reason.

Therefore I send a cURL request. But my question is, does Google Analytics count it under bounce rate?

If so, then how can I prevent not to count?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only send cURL request to get the html content, then no. GA doesn't even know about it, as long as GA's js is not requested.

Comment: Please add what you send in cURL, if it will be counted as bounce page depends on configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your site's configuration and how you've implemented Google Analytics, but for most standard situations the answer is no.

Most websites track Google Analytics via JavaScript, and if you're simply making an HTTP request for the page's content (and not executing the JavaScript), then no data will be sent to Google Analytics.

Comment: But, when I make cURL request, does javascript gets executed?